# Create n objects specified by user in C#

Tags: c#, variables, object

I have an elevator program in which the user enters the amount of people to be created.

Once the amount of people are created, they need to one by one request the lift.

The code for the person object class is:

```
class Person
{
    public int currentFloor;
    public int destinationFloor;
    public bool requestMade; // user does not request until inside the lift
    public bool isWaiting;

    // manual
    public Person(int currentFloor, int destinationFloor)
    {
        this.currentFloor = currentFloor;
        this.destinationFloor = destinationFloor;
    }

    // automatic
    public Person()
    {
        var r = new Random();
        currentFloor = r.Next(0, 4); // assign random floor as current (5 lifts)
        assignRandomDestination(); // assign random floor for destination but cannot be the same as current, else randomise destination again
    }

    private void assignRandomDestination()
    {
        var r = new Random();
        destinationFloor = r.Next(0, 4);

        if (destinationFloor == currentFloor)
        {
            assignRandomDestination();
        }
    }

    public void state(Person person, bool waiting)
    {
        if (waiting == true) { person.isWaiting = true; } else { person.isWaiting = false; }
    }

    public bool request()
    {
        return requestMade;
    }
}
```

And how would I be able to call them individually?

Comment: Create a `List<Person>` and use a loop to let the user add to it

Comment: I would hold the collection of people in a collection - e.g. List<Person>. BTW: Just a quick comment: public void state(Person person, bool waiting) is weird. If you want to know the 'state' of a 'person' then you don't need to "tell the person who they are" - i.e. pass in the person as a parameter.

Comment: This seems like a good code snippet to do a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) on, to get some pointers

Comment: Ulric, yeh you're right. Gonna change that

Comment: Also, how would I call them one by one?

Comment: You need `currentFloor = r.Next(0, 5);` for five lifts. The last number is exclusive in the `.Next()` method.

Comment: I wouldn't put `currentFloor` under `Person`. It is not unique to a person, but to all the people in the same `Elevator`. So it makes sense to move it under `Elevator`.

Comment: Replace `if (waiting == true) { person.isWaiting = true; } else { person.isWaiting = false; }` with `waiting = person.IsWaiting;`

Answer (score 0):

You should make another Class for the Elevator and add System.Collections.Generic.

```
  List<Person> passenger = new List<Person>();

  //Make an Instance of your Person.
  Person my1stperson = new Person();

  //Access their member by dot operator.
  my1stperson.currentFloor = 13;

  //After setting their fields; You can add them to the list by.
  passenger.Add(my1stperson);

  // if you have an Elevator class with currentLocation field on the elevator.

  Elevator.currentLocation = passenger[0].currentFloor; //<- only works if the field is static. Or use the Index. LinQ also works for list. Enumerables etc.

  //If not static, Instantiate the Elevator Class.
  Elevator myElevator = new Elevator();
```